# Self join on table matching DATETIME and INT columns

Tags: sql

i have a table named batch . The table structure is like this

[image: Batch]

I have tried a lot to write this query but never getting this result. I have treid like

```
select distinct a.batchid from(select batchid,bsdate,bstrength from batch)a 
inner join  
(select batchid,bsdate,bstrength from batch) b on date(a.bsdate)=date(b.bsdate) and a.bstrength=b.bstrength;

select a.batchid,a.bsdate,b.bstrength from batch a join batch b on date(a.bsdate)=date(b.bsdate) and a.bstrength=b.bstrength;
```

please help me to write this query.

Comment: What is the expected resultset based on the data above?

Comment: i dont know the answer but it should show those batches id who have common start dates as well as common strength

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.batchid a, b.batchid b
FROM batch a
JOIN batch b 
    ON CONVERT(DATE,a.bsdate) = CONVERT(DATE,b.bsdate) 
        AND a.bstrength = b.bstrength
        AND CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(a.batchid,1)) < CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(b.batchid,1))
```

Drop the converts in the `ON`-line if you want the time to match as well (since you said similar dates).
This shows only matching batches, those batches that do not match any others will not be shown. If multiple matches are made on a single record, you'll get multiple records mentioning the same record.

The last line prevents matching on itself as well as duplications like:

```
a    b
b001 b002
b002 b001
```